# rsync size differences and checksums

Tags: rsync

I am using the `rsync` command

```
rsync -av dir_a dir_b
```

Does the command check whether the size is different and also does checksums ?

Comment: See `--checksum`.

Comment: I think if you use --checksum on local directories it will be very slow. Because it needs to read all files on every run to calculate their checksums.

Answer (score 0):

The man page for `rsync` says:

> Rsync finds files that need to be transferred using a "quick check" algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed in size or in last-modified time.

In the section that describes the various options you can find the `-a` option:

```
--archive, -a            archive mode is -rlptgoD (no -A,-X,-U,-N,-H)
```

the `-c` option:

```
--checksum, -c           skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size
```

and the `-t` option:

```
--times, -t              preserve modification times
```

With all this info taken together, your `-av` options retain the default check for a difference in file size and time, but do not check for differences in file checksums.

It's pretty easy to add the `-c` option for checking file checksums:

```
rsync -acv dir_a dir_b
```

Comment: Also note that the checksum is only computed when doing network transfers by default as it's much slower to use it when doing local updates.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks, but are you saying that the presence of the `-c` option doesn't cause checksums to be computed on local transfers?

Comment: A file transfer had been done, and want to redo on files which would not have not tranferred without errors.  When an rsync fails, does it usually affect the size or just the checksum?  What would be the best options to use?

Comment: @konmi this sounds like a different question, but when I'm repeating an rsync command where the original command did not have the `-c` option, I'll usually include `-c` on the repeat command.  Most transfer failures will either fail at initial permissions checks without affecting the destination file, or during the data transfer, which will affect the destination file.  You can also investigate the `--partial` option to avoid corrupting destination files for the latter type of failures.

Comment: Well, it is the reason I have been considering checksums.

Comment: Typically you wouldn't need to specify user of checksums. `rsync -av dir_a/ dir_b` is a good safe starting point